# Doc with ObjectId Array - push value if exists, remove otherwise

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to MongoDB and mongoose.

So my model holds many fields, amongst them is an Array of ObjectIDs

```
var modelSchema = new Schema({
    //...
    inner_array: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    //...
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve with my query is:

Find a model by it's Id,

If the inner array contains a specific value remove it from the array.

If the value is not within the inner_array, push it

```
var target_id = // document id
var inner_object_id = // value to push

models.MyModel.findOne(
    {_id: target_id},
    function (err, model) {
    // IN THIS SCOPE 'INNER_OBJECT_ID' IS UNDEFINED

    // if model.inner_array contains 'inner_object_id', remove it
    // otherwise, push 'inner_object_id' into model.inner_array

    model.save();
    res.json(model); // return modified document to client
    }
);
```

I believe this can be written in a single findOneAndUpdate, but I can't figure out the syntax..

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve that using [MongooseArray.pull](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.pull) and [MongooseArray.addToSet](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.addToSet)

```
var target_id = // document id
var inner_object_id = // value to push

models.MyModel.findOne({
  _id: target_id
}, function (err, model) {
  if (model.inner_array.indexOf(inner_object_id) !== -1) {
    model.inner_array.pull(inner_object_id);
  } else {
    model.inner_array.addToSet(inner_object_id);
  }
  model.save();
  res.json(model); // return modified document to client
}
```

Comment: There was a problem with doing it this way, in the callback function - the 'inner_object_id' variable is undefined. It was defined before

Comment: Okay I seem to have passed the variable using .bind()

Comment: Glad I could help.